# Zend Framework doesn't show errors

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework, frameworks

Every error that happens in the server is not shown to me... I tried checking the requisitions in Firebug, but everytime when there is an error, the response fails.

**Only "Internal Server Error 500" is displayed.**

I think I am missing some concepts... can someone help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Check your error log. You should also set it to run in *development* mode if you want to see errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep in mind that in development environment you should turn on `error display` and set your `error reporting level` to `E_ALL`.

just write these two lines in your code or in your `init() function`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```